# Git: How to ignore file relocation? i.e. Track only its contents

Tags: git, gitignore, ignore

I'm working on a project where I need to switch between different profiles and the only way to accomplish that switch is through moving some files to a set directory.

Currently I'm doing a workaround by ignoring the set directory and copying (instead of moving) those files.

In the environment I'm working in (Unity3d) moving would be much faster than copy, but then git tracks the relocated files although nothing inside them has changed.

Can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I change this behavior?

Don't, the location of those files is obviously important, so track it. Git won't actually duplicate any data if nothing inside the files has changed, it costs you nothing in terms of overhead, but it's important that Git know where to put those files should you choose to check out a previous state.

If I've completely misunderstood your situation and you want to store the files in only one location, you can use symlinks to link them in the other directory.

Comment: The problem is that in my env (Unity3D game engine) those files, even symlinked would need to get reimported.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about version controlling the moved file at all, you could add it (in both locations) to your .gitignore file.

Other than that, I can't think of any way to tell git not to care about a file disappearing from one place in the work tree and appearing in another.  Tracking a file's content without having a sense of its location doesn't really work with the way git stores things.

It sounds like you're using making your source work tree do double duty as a deployment instance; you might think about changing that practice, as it would possibly avoid such problems.

Comment: Indeed I'm using it as deployment instance. I guess it's inevitable when working with unity. Unluckily I need to track the first directory.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I change this behavior?

You can't, no. Tracking the name and contents of a file is at the heart of git, and can't be changed.

A possible workaround, however, would be to keep a fixed directory(s) of your files and then create symlinks (or shortcuts on Windows) to them to actually use them. If you set Git to ignore the director the symlinks are in, you can edit the original files and move the symlinks around as much as you like and only content changes will be committed.

Hope this helps :)